# How to remove the darn tooltip in Qlik Sense Data Load Editor

Tags: qliksense

It drives me nuts and it wont go away. If there was a way to disable it that would be great, but even better would be a time out after a second or two like any other normal editor.

.[image: Annoying Tooltip]

Any suggestions for qlik sense desktop or browser view would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the current version (2.2.4), the answer is a no this can't be disabled.

To submit this as an idea you can log it on the [Qlik Community](https://community.qlik.com/community/pvt/ideas) for review

Comment: :( Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Xgongiveittoya did you find a solution that worked  through the Qlik Community?

Comment: Nope I don't think I ever got around to submitting an idea. I'm happy to update this question if you want to make one.

Comment: @Xgongiveittoya that is ok. I have not seen many Qlik Community requests being resolved. So far the only working solution for me it has been to comment out my code when building my expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a user script that moves the tool tip to the top left corner of the screen. [Here](https://github.com/XavierWiltbank/QlikSenseToolTipUserScript) is a link to the repo that has the user script.

Here is the meat of the userscript:

```
MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver;

var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations, observer) {
    // fired when a mutation occurs
    $(".qv-function-tip-container").css("top", "20px");
    $(".qv-function-tip-container").css("left", "20px");
});

// define what element should be observed by the observer
// and what types of mutations trigger the callback
observer.observe(document, {
    subtree: true,
    attributes: true
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Commenting out the expression will disable the syntax pop-up helper; when done, remove the // and check if any errors get highlighted.

```
// LET vUgard
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).